# Rows not grouping in LaTeX rendering with pander

Tags: r, latex, knitr, pander

When I render the following table as HTML, I get expected row grouping:

```
library(expss)
library(dplyr)
library(pander)
library(knitr)

test_data = 
  data.table(
    division = c(rep("A",5),rep("B",5)),
    group = rep(c(rep("alpha",2),rep("beta",3)),2),
    subgroup = c("red","orange","yellow","green","blue",
                 "indigo","violet","black","white","brown"),
    ins = rnorm(10),
    outs = runif(10),
    overs = seq(1,100,10)
  )

test_data = apply_labels(test_data,
                      division = "Department",
                      group = "Center",
                      subgroup = "Team",
                      ins = "In-flow",
                      outs = "Out-flow",
                      overs = "Throughput")

test_table = 
  test_data %>% 
  tab_cells(ins, 
            outs,
            overs) %>% 
  tab_cols(division %nest% group %nest% subgroup) %>%
  tab_stat_fun(identity) %>%
  tab_pivot() %>%
  drop_rc() %>%
  tab_transpose()

test_table
```

[image]

However, when I render it as a PDF, the row grouping fails, replaced with long strings of pipe-delimited characters.

```
pander(test_table)
```

[image]

I think this is more of a LaTeX than R problem, but I'm not sure if it doesn't lie in the middle with `pander`. I would prefer to output this as a PDF, given preferences from folks "up the ladder".

Comment: Try `library(huxtable); as_huxtable(test_table)`. Default output of the `expss` doesn't support pdf/latex. But huxtable as far as I know, works fine.

Comment: Just what I needed to know. Thanks so much. Care to make it an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default output of the expss doesn't support pdf/latex. But there is an excellent package `huxtable` which works with pdf:
So you need to use `as_huxtable`:

```
library(huxtable)
as_huxtable(test_table)
```